# How to manage kivy file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

when we use kivy to create interface , the kivy file content of many lines of code,
For example we have button with specific design, if I want use this button 10 times for each time should I write of properties of button ?

there is any way to manage the file? or we can make more than one kivy file to manage  and easy understands code of kivy?

Comment: Seems you want to mean [dynamic classes](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes) and [file including](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#include-file) in `kvlang`. If that doesn't help, try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: that's right thank you

Answer (score 0):

first define the class in the python file like

```
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior, RectangularRippleBehavior
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout


class CustomButon(RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior, RectangularRippleBehavior, ButtonBehaviour, MDBoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()
    
    def fxn_to_call_on_release(self):
        pass
```

and your kv file should look somewhat like this when defining the properties of the button

```
<CustomButton>:
    size_hint: None, None 
    width: dp(80)
    height: dp(32)
    elevation: 20
    radius: [dp(15), dp(15), dp(15), dp(15)]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: gch("#f3a635")
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [dp(15), dp(15), dp(15), dp(15)]
    
    MDLabel:
        text: root.text,
        halign: "center",
        font_style: "Button",
        opposite_colors: True,
        bold: True
```

The properties defined are my preferences, you can edit as you see fit.
with these definitions you can call the button in other widgets;

```
CustomButton:
    on_release: self.fxn_to_call_on_release()
    text: "Button Text"
```

you can call the button like this as many times as you wish.